# Connect on-site MongoDB replica instance to remote nodes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have a replica set running on an in-house local network. I want to add a new member running on a DigitalOcean server.
I can confirm that the local server is able to reach the remote server because as soon as I attempt to add the remote member to my local replica set, the logs on the remote changes to `connecting to 192.168.8.103:27020` which is the address of the primary on my local server.
It just keeps repeating the log and I'm stuck here.
How can I connect a remote member (cloud) to an on-site (local) replica set?
Let me know if I am missing a fundamental principle.

Answer (score 1):

Each node must be able to connect to all other nodes in the deployment. You can't have one of the nodes behind NAT which is how your home machine is set up.

Comment: Right. What's the best strategy for replicating my local data online? I'd have tried rsync but I don't know if it will be reliable in this scenario.

Comment: rsync and being a replica set member are totally different things. What is it that you want exactly?

Comment: I want to sync my local db with the cloud one so that internet users/apps can access my data.

Comment: You can use rsync for a one time copy.